# Is it possible to reference Vb.net PrintForm method in C#?

Tags: c#

C# has no printform method. Is it possible to reference Vb.net PrintForm instead of starting from scratch which would be a waste of time ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Just add a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic to your C# project.

Answer (score 1):

Anything you can do from VB.Net you can do from C# by checking the Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace.

Comment: This is of course true.  But on the Last Day, you will have to stand before the almighty in Judgment, and this sin will go on your permanent record!

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know if you can reference the PrintForm in your c# project but MSDN has a solution in c# to print a form: [Printing the form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287529(VS.71).aspx).